# Cute Diophantine equation (simplify the expression)

Tags: number-theory

Find the largest integer $n$ less than $1000$ of the form

$n=(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{\frac{4}{3}}+(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{\frac{-4}{3}}$

for some positive integer $x$.

Comment: ummm as you have typed them, the two expressions inside the parentheses are reciprocals, then negating the exponent gives two copies of the same thing

Comment: Oops, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: that's better....

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful or not: If we apply sum of cubes formula then : $$ (x + \sqrt{x^2 -1})^4 + (x + \sqrt{x^2 -1})^{-4} = \bigg((x + \sqrt{x^2 -1})^{\frac{4}{3}} + (x + \sqrt{x^2 -1})^{\frac{-4}{3}} \bigg)^3 - 3\bigg((x + \sqrt{x^2 -1})^{\frac{4}{3}} + (x + \sqrt{x^2 -1})^{\frac{-4}{3}} \bigg)$$ Then take $$ (x + \sqrt{x^2 -1}) = a$$ Thus $$a^4 + a^{-4} = n^3 - 3n$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $$u:=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}=e^{3t}\quad(t\geq0)\ .$$ 
Then
$$x={1\over2}\left(u+{1\over u}\right)=\cosh(3t)$$
and
$${n\over2}={1\over2}(u^{4/3}+u^{-4/3})=\cosh(4t)\ .$$
It follows that 
$$8x^4-8x^2+1=\cosh(12t)=4\left({n\over2}\right)^3-3\left({n\over2}\right)\ $$
(see the comment by san below), so that $x$ and $n$ are related by
$$4(2x^2-1)^2=n^3-3n+2=(n-1)^2(n+2)\ .\tag{1}$$
This implies that $n+2$ has to be a square: $n+2=m^2\geq4$. Introducing this into $(1)$ and taking the square root we obtain
$$2(2x^2-1)=(m^2-3)m\ ,$$
which then leads to
$$x^2={1\over4}(m^2-3m+2)={1\over4}(m-1)^2(m+2)\ .$$
This shows that $m+2$ has to be a square as well: $m+2=p^2\geq4$. This leads to
$$x={p(p^2-3)\over2},\qquad n=m^2-2=p^4-4p^2+2\ .$$
In this way we obtain for $p\geq2$ the pairs
$$(x,n)=\quad(1,2),\quad (9,47),\quad(26,194),\quad(55,527),\quad(99, 1154),\quad\ldots\ .$$
The answer to the original question therefore is $527$.

Comment: Brilliant answer! (+1)

Comment: Maybe you should add the formulas for the threefold and fourfold angles
$$
\cosh(3\alpha)=4 \cosh^3(\alpha)-3\cosh(\alpha)\quad\text{and}\quad
\cosh(4\alpha)=8 \cosh^4(\alpha)-8\cosh^2(\alpha)+1,
$$
see e.g. http://www.efunda.com/math/hyperbolic/multiple.cfm

Comment: The parameter $t$ in the expression $(t^3+3t^2-2)/2$ mentioned by Giovanni Resta corresponds to $p-1$ in $p(p^2-3)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \ge 1$ be an integer, and let $u = (x + \sqrt {x^2-1})$.

Then if $u^{4/3} + u^{-4/3}$ is an integer $n$, then $n > 0$, and 
by cubing we get $n^3 = u^4 + 3u^{4/3} + 3u^{-4/3} + u^{-4} = u^4 + 3n + u^{-4}$

So $n^3-3n = u^4 + u^{-4} = 2x^4 + 12x^2(x^2-1) + 2(x^2-1)^2 = 16x^4 - 16x^2 +2$

Then $(n-1)^2(n+2) = n^3-3n+2 = (4x^2-2)^2$

$n+2$ has to be the square of an integer, so let $m = \sqrt {n+2}$. Since $n >0$ we have $m \ge 2$.
Replacing $n$ with $m^2-2$, and taking square roots, we get

$(m^2-3)m = 4x^2-2$ (both sides are positive).

Then again, $(m-1)^2(m+2) = 4x^2$, and so $m+2$ has to (again) be the square of an integer, so let $t = \sqrt {m+2} \ge 2$. Replacing $m$ with $t^2-2$, and taking square roots , we get

$t^3-3t = 2x$.

Therefore the integer solutions have to be of the form $(x = \frac 12 (t^3-3t), n = (t^2-2)^2-2 = t^4-4t^2+2)$ with $t \ge 2$.

---

Additionally, we should be able to write $u$ as a cube in $\Bbb Q(t)[\sqrt{x^2-1}]$:

$u^4 = (8x^4-8x^2+1) + (8x^3-4x)\sqrt{x^2-1}$ should also be equal to $(\frac 12 n + y\sqrt{x^2-1})^3$ for some $y \in \Bbb Q(t)$.

Looking at the first coordinate we have $8x^4-8x^2+1 = \frac 12 (n^3-3n) = \frac 18 n^3 + \frac 12 3ny^2(x^2-1)$, which gives $y^2 = \frac {n^2-4}{4(x^2-1)}$

Looking at the second we get $8x^3-4x = \frac 34 n^2y + y^3(x^2-1) = y(\frac 34 n^2+ \frac 14 (n^2-4)) = y(n^2-1)$
so $y = \frac {8x^3-4x}{n^2-1}$

Now, we should have $u^{1/3} = u^{4/3} / u = (\frac 12 n + y\sqrt{x^2-1})(x - \sqrt {x^2-1})$

$= (\frac 12 nx -y(x^2-1)) + (xy - \frac 12 n)\sqrt {x^2-1}$

Now I haven't made the symbolic computation, but experimentally this simplifies down to (amazingly) $u^{1/3} = \frac t 2 + \frac 1 {t^2-1} \sqrt {x^2-1}$.

Computing $x^2-1$ reveals that $x^2-1 = \frac 14 (t^2-1)^2(t^2-4)$, so that 
$u^{1/3} = \frac t 2 + \frac 1 2 \sqrt {t^2-4}$, which is an algebraic integer when $t$ is an integer, as expected.

---

Once you "guessed" this, checking that $(\frac t 2 + \frac 1 2 \sqrt {t^2-4})^3 = x + \sqrt{x^2-1}$ and that $(\frac t 2 + \frac 1 2 \sqrt {t^2-4})^4 = \frac n2 + ? \sqrt{\ldots}$ is all the computation you need to do to check that these are the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the :

$$a+\frac{1}{a} = n$$

Let $a=\frac{p}{q}$, then $$\frac{p^{2}+q^{2}}{pq}=n$$
$$\frac{(p-q)^{2}}{pq}+2 = n $$

Let $p=q+l$, so:

1) $l = 0$ then $p=q=a=1$, and you could finish it easy.

2) $l$ > $0$ then 
$$ \frac{l^{2}}{q(l+q)} = n - 2$$, but 
First summand not a integer number. So that's false.

Comment: how could $l!$ every be $0$?

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber  that's not $l!$ that's l not equal to 0

Comment: For future reference: \neq is $\neq$

Comment: @AlexKruckman  thank you !

Comment: I don't understand what are you proving. The original equation has infinite solutions. There is no reason for assuming that $a=(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{4/3}$ is a rational number.